# Why does this crash?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been banging my head...I can't pretend to be a C++ guy...

```
    TCHAR * pszUserName = userName.GetBuffer();
SID sid;
SecureZeroMemory(&sid, sizeof(sid));
SID_NAME_USE sidNameUse;
DWORD cbSid = sizeof(sid);

pLog->Log(_T("Getting the SID for user [%s]"), 1, userName);

if (!LookupAccountName(NULL, (LPSTR)pszUserName, &sid, &cbSid, NULL, 0, &sidNameUse))
{
    pLog->Log(_T("Failed to look up user SID. Error code: %d"),1,  GetLastError());
    return _T("");
}

pLog->Log(_T("Converting binary SID to string SID"));
```

The message 'Getting the SID for user [x] is written' but then the app crashes. I'm assuming is was the `LookupAccountName` call.

EDIT:

Whoops `userName` is a MFC CString

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger? What's the crash?

Comment: As an aside, since you're passing userName as an input parameter, you don't need to caall GetBuffer.  Just pass userName directly and let the compiler use the implicit conversion to LPCTSTR.  Not sure why you're casting to LPSTR (char *) anyway since the function takes an LPCTSTR (const TCHAR *).

Comment: though, not related to original question, review the usage of TCHAR and LPSTR. It is not Ok that you're casting TCHAR* to LPSTR. Moreover, LookupAccountName expects to receive LPCTSTR.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will have to pay more close attention to things such as this. IDK why I was using get buffer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter 6 (cchReferencedDomainName) should point to a DWORD.  When the documentation says, "if the ReferencedDomainName parameter is NULL, this parameter must be zero," I believe they mean that the referenced DWORD must be 0.

Try adding:

```
DWORD cchReferencedDomainName = 0;
if (!LookupAccountName(NULL, (LPSTR)pszUserName, &sid, &cbSid, NULL, &cchReferencedDomainName, &sidNameUse))
...
```

Comment: Also note that the documentation says "If [the ReferencedDomainName parameter] is NULL, the function returns the required buffer size."  As a result, I'm not sure this is doing what you expect -- it may just be looking up the size of the buffer you need to allocate and not populating the SID.

Comment: @Nick - You were right I was using this incorrectly. I should pay better attention to the API docs...

Comment: Just ran into this as well, absolutely unclear documentation.  "Parameter" is usually pretty unambiguous, but in this case it really means "the de-referenced value of the parameter."